# Proving that an upper bound for X a sequence contained in X converges to must be the supremum of X

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Suppose that $X \subset R$ has the following two properties:

- $\exists U \in R$ s.t $x<U$ $\forall x\in X$
- $\exists$ a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N_+}$ s.t $x_n \in X$ $\forall n \in N_+$ and $lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = U$.

I want to prove that $U = sup{X}$; I have tried to below:

---

The definition of a supremum (correct me if I am wrong please), is that it is the smallest quantity greater than or equal to all the elements in our set, $X$ in this case.

Thus, for a contradicition, let us suppose that $U\not=supX$, the supremum must still exists so let us define $M := supX$ such that $U > M$ by definition.

Now set $\varepsilon := (U - M)$ and by the definition of a limit, we have that $\exists N\in N_+$ s.t $n>N \implies|a_n-\ell|<\varepsilon$ with $\ell = U$ as we have given, and remembering that $U > a_n$ $\forall n \in N_+$ s.t we end up with:
$$U-a_n<U-M \implies a_n > M$$

This violates either the definition of the supremum, or the given fact that all $a_n$ lie in $X$, thus we have a contradicition and $U = supX$

---

I am not certain if this proof is 100% correct, so if someone could validate it or give me pointers on how to improve it that would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks totally fine to me.